# Acessando metodos de uma classe em um vector de ponteiros

Tags: c++, ponteiro, vector, map

Certo, 
eu possuo uma classe Package com um método publico double calculate_cost().
**Preciso criar um `std::map<string, std::vector<Package*>>` em que eu possa iterar  pelo vetor e guardar o retorno do método calculate_cost() em uma variavel.**
(O mapa é `std::map<std::string, std::<vector<Package*>> packagemap;`)

Venho tentado de algumas formas, entre elas:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Package*>>::iterator mit;
std::vector<Package*>::iterator vit;
double total{0};
for (mit = packagemap.begin(); mit != packagemap.end(); ++mit) {
  for (vit = mit->second.begin(); vit != mit->second.end(); ++vit)
    total += mit->second[*vit].calculate_cost();
```

Mas venho a receber este erro na maioria das tentativas:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘Package*’ to ‘std::vector::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-fpermissive]       total += mit->second[*vit].calculate_cost();
>
> ```
>                              ^~~~
> ```

Esta mescla de map e vector de ponteiros tem me confundido bastante. Agradeço ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que simplifique e utilize a sintaxe do [*ranged for loop*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) que ainda lhe trás mais legibilidade ao código.

Quando itera um mapa com essa sintaxe, com:

```
for (auto elemento : colecao)
```

A chave é acessível através de `.first`, no exemplo acima seria `elemento.first` e o valor com `.second`. No seu exemplo o valor, o `second` é um vetor de ponteiros, mas pode na mesma usar outro *ranged for loop* para iterar sobre estes.

Exemplo:

```
double total = 0;
for (auto package_entry : packagemap){
    for (auto package_ptr: package_entry.second){
        total += package_ptr->calculate_cost();
    }
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/7NZ6GF)

É importante mencionar que esta sintaxe funciona em c++11 para cima.